# error in function to remove data of array which same in c++

Tags: c++

I make function to remove data of array which same in c++, so as make the process like this:

```
input:4
input:
25.50
64.25
64.25
25.50
output:
5.50
64.25
```

but the function error like this image
[image]

here the code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void removeSame(double a[int x]){
    int index[x];
    for(int z=0; z<x; z++){
        jum[z]=0;
        for(int c=0; c<x; c++){
            if(a[c]==a[z]){
                index[z]=c;   
            }   
        }   
    }
    for(int z=0; z<x; z++){
        if(z==index[z]){
            cout<<a[z]<<endl;
        }   
    }    
}
int main(){
    int n,x;
    cin>>n;
    double a[n];
    for(x=0; x<n; x++){
        cin>>a[x];   
    }
    removeSame(a[x]);
    return 0;
}
```

then when I change the code like this, an error occurs again

```
void removeSame(double a[], int x){
...
}
```

the error like this:

```
cannot convert 'double' to 'double*' for argument '1' to 'void hapusygsama(double*, int)'
```

please help me

UPDATE. thx for you all who are reply my thread

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void hapusygsama(double a[], int len){
    int index[len];
    for(int z=0; z<len; z++){
        for(int c=0; c<len; c++){
            if(a[c]==a[z]){
                index[z]=c;   
            }   
        }   
    }
    cout<<endl;
    for(int z=0; z<len; z++){
        if(z==index[z]){
            cout<<a[z]<<endl;;
        }   
    }
}
int main(){
    int n,x;
    cin>>n;
    double a[n];
    for(x=0; x<n; x++){
        cin>>a[x];   
    }
    hapusygsama(a, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why don't you just insert all items into a map, then print it?

Comment: I'm confused, why does this `double a[n];` compile? Since `n` is not a const.

Comment: Have you tried so search something by query _"c++ pass array to function"_ in Google? This is a very popular question.

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie, This is an compiler extension, I guess.

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie it's an extension in gcc

Comment: @Borgleader thank you for the info. I'll leave the comment there for others who might be confused as I where...

Answer (score 1):

Your code is illegal C++. C++ does not currently support run-time arrays. All array dimensions must include constant bounds. In addition, C++ does not permit any kind of declaring size in parameter like `double a[int x]`. You must pass the size as a separate parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You don't pass the parameters correctly to the function :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void removeSame(double a[], int x){
    //                 ^^^
    int index[x];
    for(int z=0; z<x; z++){
        jum[z]=0;
        for(int c=0; c<x; c++){
            if(a[c]==a[z]){
                index[z]=c;   
            }   
        }   
    }
    for(int z=0; z<x; z++){
        if(z==index[z]){
            cout<<a[z]<<endl;
        }   
    }    
}
int main(){
    int n,x;
    cin>>n;
    double a[n];
    //     ^^^^  ERROR : not permitted, n is not a constant
    //                   it would not compile.
    for(x=0; x<n; x++){
        cin>>a[x];   
    }
    removeSame(a, x);
    //        ^^^
    return 0;
}
```

You want to receive an array in removeSame to remove values who are the same. In you code, you try to pass a `double` value only.

**As I said, it would compile because `n` is not a constant when you declare `a` in the `main` function.**

**EDIT :** It seems it is an extension in gcc who permits this kind of syntax. But I suggest to use something more common...

You should do :

```
int main() {
    int n, x;
    cin >> n;
    double* a = new double[n];
    ...
    delete[] a;
    return 0;
}
```

In that case, the prototype of `removeSame` should be :

```
void removeSame(double* a, int x);
```

And last thing, you should verify the values entered by the user, one of the most important rule in development is : *Never trust the users input !*

Answer (score 0):

A much elegant way to achive the wished behaivour would be to use `std::unique` and `std::resize`

The code would be:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<float> myvector;
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    float b;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        cin >> b;
        myvector.push_back(b);
    }
    std::sort(myvector.begin(), myvector.end());
    myvector.resize(std::distance(myvector.begin(),std::unique (myvector.begin(), myvector.end())));

return 0;
}
```

Also in your question you have as input flaoting point numbers, while for the code you use `int`, I think you should change that too.